# Is there a way to retrieve JSON on Solidity on ERC-721?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm practicing on an ERC_721 contract and would like to know if there's a way to store JSON data directly on the contract, take a look at my approach and give your thoughts:

The `variation1.json` file uploaded to IPFS:

```
{
    "attributes": [
      {
        "trait_type": "Rank",
        "value": "1"
      }
    ],
    "description": "A simple NFT",
    "image": "Qmdasifhw89rv92enfkq128re3",
    "name": "NFT#1"
}
```

Then I would use an `object` like the one below to go with the contract that references the `file` to the `urlOfTokenURI`

```
[
  {
    "file": "variation1.json", "urlOfTokenURI": https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmdasifhw89rv92enfkqeqe23f"
  },
  {
    "file": "variation2.json", "urlOfTokenURI": "https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/Qmgvfrg34vt4u785ygbmasdsa"
  },
  ...
]
```

Then get a random number, retrieve a random `urlOfTokenURI` and mint the token to the desired address, excluding that token from the list of available tokens:

```
function mintNFT(address recipient, string memory tokenURI)
    public onlyOwner
    returns (uint256)
{
    _tokenIds.increment();
    //retrieve object, get random number and mint with the urlOfTokenURI
    //from random number index
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _mint(recipient, newItemId);
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);

    return newItemId;
}
```

What's missing here for this to work?

Can someone guide me how to proceed or have a suggestion for another approach? I'm kind of lost.

Don't understand how to mint a random NFT and instantly revealing it to the user.

Sorry in advance if it's a stupid question. I'm learning, btw.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need a real random number fn, you need to look for oracle service (e.g. Chainlink)
2. Yes, it is possible to generate an uri without publishing to IPFS. You can generate a base64 data uri instead. Check out [Example from wizard and dragon game](http://data:application/json;base64,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) and [their contract](https://etherscan.io/token/0x999e88075692bCeE3dBC07e7E64cD32f39A1D3ab)

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Strings.sol";
...
    using Strings for uint256;
    using Base64 for bytes;
...
    function tokenURI(uint256 id) public view returns (string memory) {

        string memory metadata = string(abi.encodePacked(
            "{\"name\": \"NFT#",
            id.toString(),
            "\", \"description\": \"A simple NFT\", \"attributes\":",
            "[{\"key\":\"trait_type\",\"value\":\"1\"}]",
            "}"
        ));

        return string(abi.encodePacked(
            "data:application/json;base64,",
            bytes(metadata).base64()
        ));
    }
```

Base64 lib

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

library Base64 {

    string internal constant TABLE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";

    function base64(bytes memory data) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        if (data.length == 0) return "";
        
        // load the table into memory
        string memory table = TABLE;

        // multiply by 4/3 rounded up
        uint256 encodedLen = 4 * ((data.length + 2) / 3);

        // add some extra buffer at the end required for the writing
        string memory result = new string(encodedLen + 32);

        assembly {
            // set the actual output length
            mstore(result, encodedLen)
            
            // prepare the lookup table
            let tablePtr := add(table, 1)
            
            // input ptr
            let dataPtr := data
            let endPtr := add(dataPtr, mload(data))
            
            // result ptr, jump over length
            let resultPtr := add(result, 32)
            
            // run over the input, 3 bytes at a time
            for {} lt(dataPtr, endPtr) {}
            {
                dataPtr := add(dataPtr, 3)
                
                // read 3 bytes
                let input := mload(dataPtr)
                
                // write 4 characters
                mstore(resultPtr, shl(248, mload(add(tablePtr, and(shr(18, input), 0x3F)))))
                resultPtr := add(resultPtr, 1)
                mstore(resultPtr, shl(248, mload(add(tablePtr, and(shr(12, input), 0x3F)))))
                resultPtr := add(resultPtr, 1)
                mstore(resultPtr, shl(248, mload(add(tablePtr, and(shr( 6, input), 0x3F)))))
                resultPtr := add(resultPtr, 1)
                mstore(resultPtr, shl(248, mload(add(tablePtr, and(        input,  0x3F)))))
                resultPtr := add(resultPtr, 1)
            }
            
            // padding with '='
            switch mod(mload(data), 3)
            case 1 { mstore(sub(resultPtr, 2), shl(240, 0x3d3d)) }
            case 2 { mstore(sub(resultPtr, 1), shl(248, 0x3d)) }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```